# How to make usercontrol to behave as radiobutton

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am developing tab button as user control, how can i make it to behave as radiobutton. "When the user selects one option button (also known as a radio button) within a group, the others clear automatically". thank you.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation?

Answer (score 4):

Say your custom Tab button Control is named `MyTabButton`,
Override and implement Equals, and 
then in the Click event handler in your custom control class,

```
if (this.Checked)
   foreach(Control myBut in Parent.Controls)
       if (myBut is MyTabButton && !myBut.Equals(this))
          myBut.Checked = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the behavior of radio buttons, use radio buttons.

<strike>Use javascript to hide the radio buttons and create your tab buttons in place of the original radio buttons. Feed the click events from your tab button to the original radio button. You might also want to have a common event to deselect the other tab buttons.</strike>

Your buttons will also degrade nicely if javascript is disabled.

Since you have mentioned you are using winforms, instead of using Javascript, you can override the paint method a derived RadioButton class to paint your Radiobutton as a tab. Here is a basic example

```
public class ButtonRadioButton : RadioButton {

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        PushButtonState state;
        if (this.Checked)
            state = PushButtonState.Pressed;
        else
            state = PushButtonState.Normal;

        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, state);
    }

}
```

Comment: Because your answer makes no sense. What javascript? The question is not even about the web.

Comment: It makes fine sense if this is ASP.NET. He hasn't specified, but there is nothing in his question that would indicate it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

obviously you need a container for the button, and whenever a usercontrol is selected, fire the event to container, and container deselect the other usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

Need more information as to if this is WindowsForms, WPF, ASP.NET etc.. but

If it is WPF I have written a post that explains my approach to solving this problem:
[Grouping and Checkboxes in WPF](http://www.bradcunningham.net/2009/09/grouping-and-checkboxes-in-wpf.html)

Answer (score -1):

**Edited to included the answer**

You can achieve it by overriding OnClick or OnMouseClick event. I don't get what you mean by "clearing a button", so I just change the Backcolor of it. You can easily adapt it to your Property or other needs.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public partial class MyRadioButton : Button
    {
        //Override OnClick event. - THIS IS WHERE ALL THE WORK IS DONE
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            do
            {
                /*
                    This is where you select current MyRadioButton. 
                    I'm changing the BackColor for simplicity. 
                */
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                /*
                   If parent of current MyRadioButton is null, 
                   then it doesn't belong in a group.
                */
                if (this.Parent == null)
                    break;

                /*
                    Else loop through all other MyRadioButton of the same group and clear them. 
                    Include System.Linq for this part.
                */
                foreach (MyRadioButton button in this.Parent.Controls.OfType<MyRadioButton>())
                {
                    //If button equals to current MyRadioButton, continue to the next RadioButton
                    if (button == this)
                        continue;

                    //This is where you clear other MyRadioButton
                    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
            while (false);

            //Continue with the regular OnClick event.
            base.OnClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17837035)

Comment: How does it not? I have just given a solution to an exact similar problem. Simulate the behavior of a RadioButton. It's also tested, including code sample and screenshot of results.

Comment: Excuse me then. I included the detailed answer adapted to this post needs.